# How to draw infinite earring with TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

I want to draw an infinite earring, i.e., each circle centerd at `$(\frac{1}{n},0)$` with radius `$\frac{1}{n}$` for each `$n\in \mathbf{N}$`. The figure will be the following:

[image: wanted]

I have used the following code to do the diagram:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture} 
  \foreach \n in {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,...................} 
    \draw (1/\n,0) circle (1/\n);
  \foreach \n in {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,...................}  
    \draw[fill] (1\n,0) circle (0.5pt);
\end{tikzpictute}
\end{document}
```

But it shows an error.

Comment: You don't need pgf and it is \end{tikzpicture}

Answer (score 13):

May be better than infinity you fix a large number

```
 \documentclass{article}
 \usepackage{tikz}
 \begin{document}

 \begin{tikzpicture} 
  \foreach \n in {1,2,...,2000} 
   \draw (1/\n,0) circle (1/\n);
 \end{tikzpicture}
 \end{document}
```

Edit: we can replace

```
  \foreach \n in {1,2,...,2000}
```

by

```
  \foreach \n in {1,...,2000}
```

since the step is 1

Comment: `{1,...,140}` is enough and it makes it much quicker.

Answer (score 7):

Couldn't resist to add a MetaPost version of this.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{luamplib}
\begin{document}
\begin{mplibcode}
r = 10cm; % Unit
d = 2r;
beginfig(1);
    for n = 1 upto 1000: draw fullcircle scaled (d/n) shifted (r/n, 0) ; endfor
endfig;
\end{mplibcode}
\end{document}
```

To be run with LuaLaTeX.

[image]

Comment: Surely you meant to write `for n=1 upto infinity:` (since you can in MP)!

Comment: @Thruston What's the limiting factor in that case? Don't want to keep compiling until off to the nursing home I go!

Comment: @Thruston I usually use MetaPost with the `double` numbersystem, and I lose the habit to use the `infinity` constant, since I thought that `infinity` would have a much bigger value than `2^12-1`. But I must correct myself: `infinity` is still equal to 2^12-1=4095,99998… in `double` mode, despite the fact that MetaPost can handle much bigger numerics then; I've just checked it. It looks like an oversight from MetaPost's developers.

Comment: @1010011010 I was just making an in-joke:  one of the amusing features of Metafont/Metapost is that it actually defines a constant `infinity`.  An example of Knuth's humour I think, but occasionally it is useful; for example if you have a path `p` then `point infinity of p` is always at the far end of `p`.

Comment: If you wonder why I've drawn up to 1000 circles, it is because I wanted to make the white point (the last circle), which is left at the origin in most of the other pictures, completely disappear (in appearance I mean). I first try with n = 100, and it was still here. So I went for n = 1000… I confess, I was too lazy to search a more optimal value for n :-)

Answer (score 6):

Another solution leveraging nodes' alignment property:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}

\pgfkeys{tikz/.cd,
  num of circles/.store in=\numcirc,
  num of circles=100,
  circle initial size/.store in=\circlesize,
  circle initial size=3cm,
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \n in {1,...,\numcirc}{
\pgfmathsetmacro\actualsize{\circlesize/\n}
\node[anchor=west,circle,draw,inner sep=\actualsize pt] at (0,0){};
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

Comment: Watch out for the tiny white dot just to the right of the centers of the circles.

Comment: @BenjaminMcKay: That's due to the low number of samples used. Just add `\begin{tikzpicture}[num of circles=2000]` and it will disappear.

Answer (score 4):

A PSTricks solution:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{multido}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{xfp}

% parameters
\def\circles{100}
\def\radius{3}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(\fpeval{2*\radius},\fpeval{2*\radius})
  \multido{\i = 1+1}{\circles}{\pscircle(\fpeval{\radius/\i},\radius){\fpeval{\radius/\i}}}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

...and in case the drawing of the circle perimeters are done with a too thick pen:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{multido}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{xfp}

% parameters
\def\circles{100}
\def\radius{3}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(\fpeval{2*\radius},\fpeval{2*\radius})
  \multido{\i = 1+1}{\circles}{\pscircle[linewidth = 0.5\pslinewidth](\fpeval{\radius/\i},\radius){\fpeval{\radius/\i}}}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: output2]